# Multi text search with angular material table

Tags: angular, html-table, angular-material

The search currently works fine. But I have a specific requirement for search.

[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m6xfsc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Lets say I need to search the first row `Hydrogen Lithium`, the user should be able to enter the following:

`*Hy*Li` and I should get the output `Hydrogen Lithium`

How do I achive this? I need break the `*` into an `array` and derive my search based on all the search items after splitting the `*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to modify the [filter predicate](https://material.angular.io/components/table/api#classes) of your datasource.

Example forked from your Stackblitz and based on your search requirements [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yzgx33).

Specifically:

```
constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) {
    this.dataSource.filterPredicate =
        (data: Element, filter: string) => {
            const searchArray = filter.split("*");
            let filterMatch = true;
            let prevIndex = 0;
            searchArray.forEach(subString => {
                const strIndex = data.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(subString.toLowerCase());
                if (strIndex === -1 || strIndex < prevIndex) {
                    filterMatch = false;
                } else {
                    prevIndex = strIndex;
                }
            });
            return filterMatch;
        };
}
```

(Apologies this is quite verbose - will review when I get a moment!)